# About audits in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I need to do the auditing in database, but different the normal process that administrator use, (active audit in first installation or alter ) I don't have time window for this.

My scenario:
tree users with select grant just. But, for others users in same place, using the global user whit delete, update grant.

And I don't simply change the grant these users, because others applications use in font the same user and password.

Exist other form that I take a report with , what each one user does in database?

Comment: I'm guessing that English isn't your first language.  Unfortunately, I can't follow the question you're trying to ask.  Perhaps adding a bit of code would clarify things a bit (i.e. I do X and I want Y to be recorded, I do A and I want B to be recorded)?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, excuse any errors or agreement error.

My question is a concept so much, but explain.

I have users who have their logins, but there is a login that has some privileges that also and the same User used in important processes in the environment and is in source code.

At one point in the past knew the password for this login, and the more I say to access the environment with their respective login and password in some cases, they use this login with privileges.

As I have not, by default, a native audit Oracle configured in my environment, I wonder if through tables and views I can map out what such User made using a PL SQL DEVELOPER.
The worst and I have no time available to make this change, let offline the database, adjust and available.